ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' with installing python3.10
I tried to install on ubuntu 24 LTS python 3.10 (default python version is 3.12) and after I did : sudo apt update
And this error has shown :
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 3, in 
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
Can someone help ? I've tried everything i saw but no results

"I tried to install on ubuntu 24 LTS python 3.10" how exactly? Did you change the system's default python3 version (for example via update-alternatives, or by manually symlinking /usr/bin/python3)?

This question is similar to: Problem with sudo apt update in Ubuntu 18.04: Post-Invoke-Success if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
